# sending a charset in the Content-Type header

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, character-encoding, header

i use jquery $ajax to post a contact form to my email.

but encoding is wrong and i see question marks.

i figured i should set the content-type but cant manage to do so.

am using asp

thx

Answer (score 0):

We can set encoding by **contentType** and **mimeType**

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url: "/send_email.html",
     data: data,
     dataType: 'html', // or json

     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     mimeType: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',

     success:  function(return_data){
          // check return_data if everything is ok 
     }
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/